# Populating the values in DDL based on the value selected in other DDL In ASP

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a small program which populates the values in one DLL based on the value selected 
by the user in other DLL.

This I'm saying need to be done using ASP. I have used it before uisng Bind().

Suggestions are welcome...!!

Comment: Set AutoPostBack = true on the first one.

Comment: Please post you .cs code and html.